# Index of a record in a sorted relations

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails-3, binary-search

Given I have a sorted relation (perhaps done by

```
  SELECT id 
    FROM model 
   WHERE type = 'a' 
ORDER BY name`
```

...), now I want to quickly get the index of a specific record **e.g record id#15003**.

How should I do it in MySql [I'm a Rails developer]?

Comment: A few things I'm thinking of: `select index_of(15003) in (select id from ...)` but I cannot find something like an index_of operator inside MySql manual

Comment: What do you mean by "index of a specific record"?

Comment: Or develop a recursive ruby `binary_find(wanted_name, left_offset, right_offset)` which will execute `select name from [condition & order] limit left_offset, 1` and then `select name from [condition & order] limit right_offset, 1`, compare them with `wanted_name` to determine whether to find between (`left_offset`, `left+right/2_offset`) or (`left+right/2_offset`, `right_offset`) next

Comment: @OMG Pnies: e.g a relation contains Rec#1, Rec#7, Rec#10, Rec#13, etc. Then index of Rec#7 inside such relation is **2**. I want to quickly calculate that **2**

Answer (score 2):

Assuming by index you mean row number.  That is, if the results come back '1, 7, 9,...' then the "index of 9" is 3, it is the third row.

You want what are variously called "Window functions" or "statistical functions" like row_number().

MySQL doesn't have them.  Sorry.

However, though I'm not a RAILS developer, I have to assume you can get results in an array and search the array and return an index number?

**EDIT**: Based on your comment to Brad's answer, if you are doing this for the sake of paginating results, then look at the LIMIT and OFFSET.  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html

Comment: Given my relations have 10k of records, is fetching all ids an inexpensive things to do?

Comment: Depends on how often you do it.  If you have to do it frequently, as part of a simple action like saving a blog comment, then you are in trouble.  If it is part of some batch-type operation that runs hourly or daily and does not have anybody waiting for it, then you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something such as this: http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/02/how-to-number-rows-in-mysql/

I believe this is going to require you to select all results up to your desired result. So, if your record is at index 15003, you must select records 1-15003. Obviously this is not efficient or scalable... Perhaps there is a better way to approach the problem? Why do you need the index anyway? Why not place a more restrictive WHERE condition on the original SQL?

Comment: So I have a ranked table for student score, and displayed them using paging. I want to quickly navigate to a page where that student located. Do you have another suggestion?

Comment: One idea is to pre-assign sequential numbers to the students. When you want to the find the page for a specific student, use this pre-assigned index to determine which page he would fall on. This assumes you are going to have few writes and many reads. Adding a record will force you to re-create your index but your reads will be much faster.